# Unable to change Excel sheet tab name when exporting SSRS report?

Tags: excel, reporting-services

When I export the SSRS report to Excel, the report does not have the desired sheet tab name, despite the Tablix Properties 'Name' field having a value other than the report name.

I created a report in Report Builder and have set the 'Name' field in the Tablix Properties. The report matches configurations in every set of properties I can find to the first version of the report. However, since it prints to one page only, I can't use the page break solutions suggested by other posts.

In v1 (not made by me, and the creator is not with the company anymore), the exported report has a sheet tab named 'Shipments', but when I perform the same action in v2, the tab is instead the report name.

I am using Report Builder version 15.0.19914.0 and Excel through Office 365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tablix's PageName property controls the tab name in Excel, not the Name.

In Visual Studio, the F4 button will open the Properties window.

[image]

In Report Builder, click on the Properties check box in the View tab to open the properties window.

[image]

[image]

You can use static text, a field (as in the example) or an expression.

Comment: Is that a menu within Report Builder? When I open Tablix Properties in Report Builder, I see only General, Visibility, Filters, and Sorting in the left hand column.

Comment: @gp_zachjohnson - the Properties window has more properties than the tablix properties pop-up (for some god-forsaken reason). Go to View and check Properties.